# Getting org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound error, while using Spring Restful Web Service

Tags: java, angularjs, spring

I am using spring restful webservice along with angular JS. I am trying to connect with my backend code but could not able to do so. I am not able to figure out where exactly I am going wrong.

Here is my angular code :

```
app.constant('REST_URI', 'http://localhost:8181/rest/');

app.factory('FeedbackService',['$http', 'REST_URI', function ($http, REST_URI) {

    const addFeedbackAPI = REST_URI + 'feedback/addFeedback';

    var addFeedback = function(feedbackData){
        return $http.post(addFeedbackAPI, feedbackData);
    };

   return {
       addFeedback : addFeedback
   };

}]);

app.controller('feedbackController', ['$scope', 'FeedbackService', function ($scope, FeedbackService) {

    $scope.feedbackData = {};

    $scope.addFeedback = function () {

        $scope.feedbackData.registerDate = new Date();

        FeedbackService.addFeedback($scope.feedbackData).then(
            function (successResponse) {
                $scope.feedbackResponse = successResponse;
            },
            function (errorResponse) {
                $scope.feedbackResponse = errorResponse;
            }
        );
    };
}]);
```

## web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">


    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/rootApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class> org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener </listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>

        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/config/webApplicationContext.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>springrest</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

## Controller

```
@RestController(value = "/rest/feedback/")
public class FeedbackController {

    @Autowired
    private FeedbackService feedbackService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "addFeedback", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public long addFeedback(@RequestBody Feedback feedback) {
        return feedbackService.addFeedback(feedback);
    }
}
```

But I am getting 404 error in logs :

console :

```
http://localhost:8181/rest/feedback/addFeedback 404 ()
```

server : 
    01-Feb-2017 10:05:49.339 WARNING [http-nio-8181-exec-9] org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound.noHandlerFound No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/rest/feedback/addFeedback] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springrest'

---

Answer (score 0):

use `@RestController(value = "/feedback/")`

instead of `@RestController(value = "/rest/feedback/")`

because you have already used `/rest/*` in your `web.xml` you need not to give this in java controller.